# Why is the statement unreachable?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
int i = 0, j = 5;   
tp: for (;;) {
    i++;  
    for (;;) {
        if(i > --j) {
            break tp; 
        } 
    } 
    System.out.println("i =" + i + ", j = " + j); //Unreachable statement, why?
}
```

I thought the statement is reachable because there is the break statement before, therefore the statement  followed by `System.out.println` *can complete normally*, since `System.out.println` is reachable. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have two infinite loops. Change

```
break tp;
```

To

```
break;
```

And that statement is reachable.

Comment: Breaking to the outer loop ought to take it to the `println`, since execution resumes at the statement following the labeled statement. Conversely, an ordinary `break` wouldn't - you'd just wind up back in the outer infinite loop. Am I reading this incorrectly?

Comment: No, the labeled break takes it to outside the body of the outter loop. Not to the last statement inside the loop body. You could have tried it.

Comment: Indeed, the key thing is to use just break statement instead of labeled break. Thank you.

Comment: [I did try it](http://ideone.com/l16c22), but I misread the OP's code and thought the `println` was outside the outer loop rather than inside.

Answer (score 3):

Your break statement brings to back to the start of the outer loop (`tp` label). That's why you can never reach the `println` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop is infinite. If there were nothing inside it, it should be clear that the `print` is unreachable. If you add a `break tp` inside it it will break the enclosing loop not the inner one, so the statement remains unreachable.

Either use `break` to break the inner loop or label the inner loop with `tp` to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

your code is like

```
L1 : INFINITE LOOP
 {
  L2 : INFINITE LOOP
  {
    break to  return to L1
  }
  SOP("SOmething")
 }
```

So whenever the loop L2 breaks, it takes control back to loop L1 and again the loop L2 starts.
This will continue forever and the control will never be able to exit loop L2 and reach SOP statement, thus SOP statement is unreachable.